# Fixing N+1 queries in Rails that need a counter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm pretty new to optimizing my queries, I have an N+1 query and it seems it needs a counter, but I'm not really sure how to proceed:

```
...
SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM (SELECT 1 FROM `photos` WHERE (`photos`.attachable_id = 4864 AND `photos`.attachable_type = 'Recipe')) AS subquery
SQL (2.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM (SELECT 1 FROM `votes` WHERE (`votes`.voteable_id = 4864 AND `votes`.voteable_type = 'Recipe') AND (`votes`.`vote` = 1)) AS subquery
SQL (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM (SELECT 1 FROM `votes` WHERE (`votes`.voteable_id = 4864 AND `votes`.voteable_type = 'Recipe') AND (`votes`.`vote` = 0)) AS subquery
SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM (SELECT 1 FROM `photos` WHERE (`photos`.attachable_id = 4865 AND `photos`.attachable_type = 'Recipe')) AS subquery
SQL (2.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM (SELECT 1 FROM `votes` WHERE (`votes`.voteable_id = 4865 AND `votes`.voteable_type = 'Recipe') AND (`votes`.`vote` = 1)) AS subquery
SQL (2.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM (SELECT 1 FROM `votes` WHERE (`votes`.voteable_id = 4865 AND `votes`.voteable_type = 'Recipe') AND (`votes`.`vote` = 0)) AS subquery
...
```

So I have two odd things that pose a problem here. I have this polymorphic `vote` model, and I need to sum up all them, and basically if someone had casted a down vote it has value of `0` on the `vote` column, and a `1` if the users had cast an up vote. However it looks like It creates this insane query.

How could I remedy this?

---

I think the thing that is causing this starts with this method in my view:

```
<%= recipe.votes.tally %>
```

And this is the way I'm tallying my votes:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :up, where(:vote => true)
  scope :down, where(:vote => false)

  def self.tally
    self.up.count - self.down.count
  end

end
```

But since I'm doing it for each Object it has to do this logic many times, we end out with a crazy N+1.

Comment: It would help a lot, if you could paste a bit of you logic here...

Comment: Thanks @mdrozdziel, I added some stuff there.

Comment: I guess the challenging thing here is that I can't just `sum` the column because false is `0` and true is `1` so records with false dont count when summed.

Comment: How to you fetch recipe in the controller? Won't adding includes(:votes) there solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write,

> I think the thing that is causing this starts with this method in my view:
>
> < % = recipe.votes.tally % >

you can find more certainty by getting yourself a recipe instance in script/console
and executing **recipe.votes.tally** there

Not quite sure, and this is a bit vague, but is it possible you should look at placing your tally method in the recipe model? -- Stephan

Comment: Thanks Stephen so here is what I ended out doing; sorta what you are saying, I put a method in my `recipe` model and made my tally method update a column named `votes_count`, so when someone casts a vote it increments or decrements the vote count for that column. The downside is that all the things that are `votable` now need this column but the performance gains are worth it.